# I was trying to build this docker image based on the following Dockerfile until this happened

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Command that triggered this error:

```
docker build -t developerfolio:latest .
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine

WORKDIR ./app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm audit fix

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Error message snapshot (Terminal):

[image]

Comment: source code : https://github.com/ismailalabou/developerFolio/tree/1.3

Comment: I don't know where you've copied the Dockerfile from, and it's not the problem you're asking about, but you should **not** be making changes like `npm audit fix` in there - builds should be reproducible.

Comment: hello @jonrsharpe, i was running an old version of the Dockerfile (v1.3), here is the new version (i will give it a try):
https://github.com/saadpasta/developerFolio/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Should you not change your WORKDIR to `/app/node-server` before running `npm start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem/issue encountered due to misconfigured dockerfile.
the docker image is now built succefully.